# Find and replace each instance of a single string with another from a list or file

Tags: xml, linux, awk, sed, replace

I have a large XML file with multiple instances of the string `REPLACEME`. In a second file, I have a list of strings (which contain commas) such as:

```
58,-21,0
234,-38,0
```

I'd like to replace each instance of `REPLACEME` in the first file with one of the values from the second file, and then move on to the next instance.

I've looked at bash (sed, awk, perl) and Powershell. I've been told I shouldn't use for loops, but use file loops and parse the file back in. So I've tried this:

```
file2=/file2.txt
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
  sed '0,/REPLACEME/s//$line/' /file1.xml
done < "$file2"
```

But it doesn't do anything. Possibly because the XML files have symbols? It doesn't error, it just doesn't do anything.

Happy to ditch my code entirely or switch parsers if I can find something that can achieve the replacement result?

EDIT:
Asked for an example of the XML. The XML markup is part of a KML file, the strings are coordinate points. Example below:

```
<Placemark>
    <name>5005</name>
        <MultiGeometry>
            <Polygon>
                -snip-
            </Polygon>
            <Point>
            <gx:drawOrder>1</gx:drawOrder>
                <coordinates>REPLACEME</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
```

There are hundreds of such entries in this file, which need to be filled using corresponding coordinates from the list in file2.

Comment: by one value you mean `58,-21,0` or `58` ,`-21` , `0` so on ?

Comment: Where do you need to place the modified file1 - write it out ? or update the current file1 ?

Comment: You have showed an example of the second file. Can you also show a sample of the XML file, as well as the output that corresponds to this?

Comment: No, the single value is "58,-21,0". I thought the symbols and commas could pose a problem, so I included them.
XML example would be like so:
<Placemark>
 <name>5000</name>
  <MultiGeometry>
   <Point>
    <coordinates>REPLACEME</coordinates>
   </Point>
  </MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
The above would be part of a file with over 500 of these entries that all need replacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like all you need is:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0; next} /REPLACEME/{sub(/REPLACEME/,a[++c])} 1' file2.txt file1.xml
```

The normal advice is to use an XML-aware tool like xmlstarlet or xmllint when manipulating xml files but I personally don't know either well enough to solve this problem with them and IMHO it's not necessary for what you're doing, assuming `REPLACEME` only occurs in the context shown in your example.

When manipulating text the best advice isn't "don't use **for** loops" it's "don't use **shell** loops" so using a while loop in this context is also a bad approach. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

When doing anything other than just manipulating text (e.g. reading a list of URLs from a file to run `curl` on) then a shell loop can be appropriate and in that case (but also consider `xargs` instead) and then yes you should avoid `for`, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor.

Your sed script `sed '0,/REPLACEME/s//$line/'` won't let `$line` expand since it's inside single quotes.

Comment: Thanks so much for adding context for me on shell loops and problems with my script. I appreciate the extra effort to educate me and not just provide an answer.

I'm correct in assuming I need to pipe the output from awk back into a file? Is best practice to pipe it into a new file, or is piping back into the 'file1.xml' acceptable also? Seperate question I know, but for completeness sake...

Comment: You're welcome. Never redirect output of any command back to the input file as doing so can empty your input file before your command runs. Do `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file` instead for any given command.

Comment: @EdMorton WRT your 2nd point about `0,/RE/`, unlike awk, sed parses numeric addresses as line numbers. And GNU sed allows to [start the range on line number 0](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Special-addressing-forms) so that `/RE/` can possibly end the range on the first line (whereas `1,/RE/` cannot).

Comment: Ah, I see. range expressions are inherently evil so I never use them. I should've just said that instead of guessing at what it meant :-)! I removed that statement from my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using a combination of `sed` and `ed` - the `sed` creates `ed` commands from your `file2.txt`:

```
(sed 's|.*|/REPLACEME/s/REPLACEME/&/|' file2.txt; echo '1,$p') | ed -s file1.xml
```

The first `REPLACEME` in the XML file is replaced by the first line of `file2.txt`, the second by the second, and so on.

If you want to save the changes to the file instead of just **p**rinting them to standard output, replace the `echo '1,$p'` with `echo w`.

If you have more lines in `file2.txt` than there are REPLACEME lines in `file1.xml`, `ed` will print out a question mark for each on standard error. If you don't want to see those, redirect to `/dev/null`:

```
$ (sed 's|.*|/REPLACEME/s/REPLACEME/&/|' file2.txt; echo '1,$p') | ed -s file1.xml 2>/dev/null
<Placemark>
    <name>5005</name>
        <MultiGeometry>
            <Polygon>
                -snip-
            </Polygon>
            <Point>
            <gx:drawOrder>1</gx:drawOrder>
                <coordinates>58,-21,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
```

If not for the `2>/dev/null`, your sample files would have also produced one `?` because `file2.txt` has two lines and there's only one REPLACEME in the XML file.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I appreciate non-destructive examples, helps to break it down and test it out. This command doesn't seem to be working though; it just prints two lines with the ? character. Ed's answer works, but I wouldn't mind understanding what sed and ed are doing in this scenario?

Comment: @TylerJones If you have more lines in file2.txt than there are REPLACEME lines in file1.xml, you'll get question marks on standard error. They can be ignored. Redirect standard error to /dev/null if you don't want to see them.